# For-Loop ends before upper limit is reached

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason I can't comprehend my for Loop "breaks" the program.

For lower values it works fine, the break of point seems to be 45 seconds (600 bitmaps) anything above that and the loops simply exists and the function doesn't even finish.

Here is the Loop:

```
 public void GenBitmaps()
    {
        timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 40);
        int BitmapCount = (int)((timespan.Minutes * 60 + timespan.Seconds) * 1000 / ((double)timer1.Interval));
        bitmaps = new Bitmap[BitmapCount];

        double size = StartSize.Height;

        for (int i = 0; i < BitmapCount; i++)
        {
            this.Text = i.ToString() + " " + BitmapCount.ToString();
            bitmap = new Bitmap(StartSize.Width, (int)size);

            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
                {
                    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                }
            }
            bitmaps[i] = bitmap;
            size -= StartSize.Height / (float)BitmapCount;
        }          
    }
```

Comment: It might be that obvious that you are running out of memory there?  How large are your bitmaps, heigh * width?

Comment: Can you define "break"?  Is there an error?  What is the indication of the failure, and what is the state of the application at that time?

Comment: @Daniel: the bitmaps start at 200x600 and get smaller

Comment: Try taking out the bitmap[i] = bitmap.  If it runs then you are probably just running out of resources (memory).  Put in a try catch block.

Comment: @Blam Commenting out the bitmaps[i] = bitmap; does not help, according to the taskmagaer it program uses only 200mb

Comment: Wow, try a try catch block and hopefully you get an error.  A reach but there might be a size value that breaks it.

Comment: Wowowowow, you are doing this in some kind of TIMER event???

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a 64-bit WinForms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-64-bit-winforms-applicatio)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your bitmap size gets close to zero and some exception is thrown during bitmap construction. Try wrapping bitmap constructor in try/catch